# Can I use a single `default_random_engine` to create multiple normally distributed sets of numbers?

Tags: c++, random

I want to generate a set of unit vectors (for any arbitrary dimension), which are evenly distributed across all directions. For this I generate normally distributed numbers for each vector component and scale the result by the inverse of the magnitude.

**My question**: Can I use a single `std::default_random_engine` to generate numbers for all components of my vector or does every component require its own engine?

Afaik, each component needs to be Gaussian-distributed independently for the math to work out and I cannot assess the difference between the two scenarios. Here's a MWE with a single RNG (allocation and normalization of vectors is omitted here).

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> GenerateUnitVecs(size_t dimension, size_t count)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> result;

    /* Set up a _single_ RNG */
    size_t seed = GetSeed(); // system_clock
    std::default_random_engine gen(seed);
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0, 1.0); 

    /* Generate _multiple_ (independent?) distributions */
    for(size_t ii = 0; ii < count; ++ii){
        std::vector<double> vec;
        for(size_t comp = 0; comp < dimension; ++comp)
            vec.push_back(distribution(gen)); // <-- random number goes here

        result.push_back(vec);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Avoid `default_random_engine` - you don't know what it will be (IMHO it should never have been allowed in the standard) and in some implementations it may be as bad as `rand`. State the random number engine you want/need explicitly - please - most likely this will be `mt19937`.

Comment: There is a big mathematical problem in your code: you will not get a spherical distribution this way. Before going to code you should find the right mathematical model.

Comment: Tip: Using a flat distribution of spherical coordinate angle or Euler angles will not help you either!

Comment: @Oliv My intention was to do something like http://corysimon.github.io/articles/uniformdistn-on-sphere/ (see method 1). May I kindly ask you to hint at what I did wrong? Thank you

Comment: @Jesper Juhl Thanks for pointing that out. I never bothered to check how C++ manages RNGs, since I barely ever use them.

Comment: @Jersey Whoah what a surprise! Did not know this trick. I ll reminber it , thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The OP asked:*

> My question: Can I use a single std::default_random_engine to generate numbers for all components of my vector or does every component require its own engine?

---

I would suggest as others have stated in the comments about not using `std::default_random_engine` and instead use `std::random_device` or `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`

---

To use `random_device` for a `normal distribution` or `Gaussian` it is quite simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>

int main() {

    std::random_device rd{};
    std::mt19937 gen{ rd() };

    // values near the mean are the most likely
    // standard deviation affects the dispersion of generated values from the mean
    std::normal_distribution<> d{5,2};

    std::map<int, int> hist{};
    for ( int n=0; n<10000; ++n ) {
        ++hist[std::round(d(gen))];
    }
    for ( auto p : hist ) {
        std::cout << std::setw(2)
                  << p.first << ' ' << std::string(p.second/200, '*' ) << '\n';
    }
}
```

---

To use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`: there is a little more work but just as easy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <chrono>

class ChronoClock {
public:
    using Clock = std::conditional_t<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady,
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
        std::chrono::steady_clock>;

    static unsigned int getTimeNow() {
        unsigned int now = static_cast<unsigned int>(Clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
        return now;
    }
};

int main() {       

    /*static*/ std::mt19937 gen{}; // Can be either static or not.

    gen.seed( ChronoClock::getTimeNow() );

    // values near the mean are the most likely
    // standard deviation affects the dispersion of generated values from the mean
    std::normal_distribution<> d{5,2};

    std::map<int, int> hist{};
    for ( int n=0; n<10000; ++n ) {
        ++hist[std::round(d(gen))];
    }
    for ( auto p : hist ) {
        std::cout << std::setw(2)
                  << p.first << ' ' << std::string(p.second/200, '*' ) << '\n';
    }
}
```

As you can see from the examples above where these are shown [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) from `cppreference.com`there is a single engine, single seed, and a single distribution, that it is generating random numbers or sets of random numbers with a single engine.

---

**EDIT** - *Additionally you can use a class that I've written as a wrapper class for `random engines` and `random distributions`*. You can refer to this answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48115400/1757805).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are not generating random numbers in parallel. Then theoretically, there is no problem with generating random independent Gaussian vectors with one engine.

Each call to `std::normal_distribution`'s `()` operator gives you a random real-valued number following specified Gaussian distribution. Successive calls of `()` operator give you independent samples. The implementation in `gcc` (my version: `4.8`) uses the Marsaglia Polar method for standard normal random number generation. You can read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method) Wikipedia page for more detail.

However, for rigorous scientific research that demands high quality randomness and a huge amount of random samples, I would recommend using the [Mersenne-Twister engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister#k-distribution) (`mt19937` 32-bit or 64-bit) instead of the default engine, since it is based on a well-established method, has long period and performs well on statistical random tests.